# Alternative header in php

Tags: php, html

Is there's an alternative way to the header in PHP to redirect the page?
Because I can't write any statement before the header.
Snippet:-

```
echo "code";
header ("location: page.php");
```

Comment: This is unclear. What are you asking? How to use a header when you have output before the redirect? Please clarify.

Comment: This correct so that I ask about way to output message then go to another page.

Comment: If you want to display a message, then redirect, you will need to use Javascript.

Comment: If not annoying for you can give me idea or test code.thanks rasclatt

Comment: or you could try to do it yourself and when you get stuck come back and ask again

Comment: Use HTML meta redirect (just google it).

Comment: Ok  can try it then return if problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do so.
- You can set delay in your code so that that much amount of time the page stops on that page and after that it will execute next line, for that you can use 
`sleep ( int $seconds )`

- You can write

  window.alert("your message");

so it will display your message in alert popup and once you will confirm it will execute after lines.

- You can also set your message in some session variable and after redirecting your page just write down your message from the session variable with some dialogbox, and when it will appear clear your session variable.